# Codeigniter / jQuery update database without reload/redirect

Tags: jquery, database, codeigniter

I've been trying to update a database row without having to reload a page or redirect to another page to commit the query. I've tried anything I could, but no luck. I have a gallery page. When a user submits an artwork, by default it's not approved and can be approved by an authorized user such as a moderator. The moderator page lists unapproved artworks. The database has a column called approved, its value being either 0 or 1.

Here is my codes.

UPDATE:

Thanks a lot for taking your time. I made the changes you said but it's still not working. Admittedly, I'm not really so good with jQuery/Ajax, so it must be a mistake on my part as to why it didn't work. My codes are now like this:

Model function:

```
function approve($id)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('galeri', array('approved' => '1')); 
    return TRUE;
}
```

Controller

```
function approve($id)
{
    if ($this->galeri->approve($id)) {
        echo("VALID");
    }
}
```

HTML

```
.
.
.
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var test = $("a.approval").attr("id").replace('artid-','');
            $.ajax({
                  type: 'post',
                  url: 'approve',
                  data: test,
                  beforeSend: function() {
                    parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
                  },
                  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    if (data == "VALID") {
                        parent.slideUp(300,function() {
                          parent.remove();
                        });
                    };
                  }
            });
          });
        });
    </script>
.
.
.
    <?php foreach ($query->result() as $list): ?>
        <span style="display: block">
            <?php echo $list->path; ?> -- <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="artid-<?php echo $list->id; ?>'" class="approval">Approve artwork</a>
        </span>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
.
.
.
```

Comment: in your CI PHP, use [Active Record](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) to easily update your db, then `echo` back a string or JSON object telling your jQuery AJAX `what's up!`

Comment: from what little i've looked at so far, yoru function `approve($id)` needs an `echo` return in order for your jquery ajax to do anything based on returned data.  That said, your params for `success` ar `(data, textStatus, jqXHR)`, where `data` is the echo returned by php

Comment: on which event you want to fire that ajax request?I mean that on clicking that approval link or what?

Comment: Yes. The event should be triggered when the approval link is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

You're not echoeing back anything and thus success is not evaluating anything

Try adding:

*PHP*

```
function approve($id) {
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('galeri', array('approved' => '1')); 
    return TRUE; // you could use several dif methods to check if updated
}

function approve($id) {
    if ($this->galeri->approve($id)) {
       echo("VALID");
    }
}
```

*ajax*

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'approve',
      data: test, // Not sure what to put here. 
      beforeSend: function() {
        parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
      },
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if (data == "VALID") {
            parent.slideUp(300,function() {
              parent.remove();
            });
        };
      }
});
```

also, I would suggest removing the "e.preventDefault" on your link for severl reasons

- you dont have to put a click command on a link
- if you do, set it's href to `javascript:void(0)`, works as good as e.preventDefault with less possible crossbrowser function reading issues (tissue?)
- as previously noted, some versions of some browsers (cough ie cough) dont like seeing e.preventDefault at the begining of a function, and i cnt remember what ver, but i had that problem once and nearly drove me nuts figuring out i had to remove my prevent default! (lol)

Answer (score 0):

i think you should fire that jquery/ajax request on some event.So if i consider that you are trying to execute that ajax when user click on approval link then try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

       $('.approval').each(function(){
                  $(this).click(function(){
               var test = $("a.approval").attr("id").replace('artid-','');
            $.ajax({
                  type: 'post',
                  url: 'approve',
                  data: test,
                  beforeSend: function() {
                    parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
                  },
                  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    if (data == "VALID") {
                        parent.slideUp(300,function() {
                          parent.remove();
                        });
                    };
                  }
            });
          });

      });
    });


        });
    </script>
.
.
.
    <?php foreach ($query->result() as $list): ?>
        <span style="display: block">
            <?php echo $list->path; ?> -- <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="artid-<?php echo $list->id; ?>'" class="approval">Approve artwork</a>
        </span>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
.
.
.
```

And please check that your global_csrf protection in config.php file is set to true of false.

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
```

if it's set to true then you need to pass csrf token also in your ajax request otherwise codeigniter will not execute your request.

Comment: if your $config['csrf_protection'] is set to true then let me know i will tell you how to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for taking your time and answering. I figured out the problem was the 'data' property of $.ajax. And this is the solution I came up with (which exactly is working the way I want):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('a.approval').click(function () {
                var test = $(this).attr('id');
                $.ajax({   
                    url: "site/approve/"+test, 
                    type: "POST", 
                    // data: test,
                    success: function(data) {

                        $('.asdf-'+test).css("background-color", "green");
                    }
                })
            });
        });
</script>
```

Is this a healthy way of using $.ajax, I'd like to know.